# SpringBoot test: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for ReactiveMongoRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-test, reactive-mongo-java

I'm trying to test service-class of reactive mongoDB application, created on SpringBoot.

I don't use embedded mongodb! I'm only trying to mock repository

This is reactive mongo repository:

```
package com.spb.budget_server.repository;

public interface EntryRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Entry, String> {
  }
```

Repository, which should use it:

```
package com.spb.budget_server.repository.impl;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Repository
public class EntryRepositoryImpl {

    private EntryRepository entryRepository;
    //
}
```

And test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {EntryRepositoryImpl.class, EntryRepository.class})   
public class EntryServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private EntryRepositoryImpl entryRepositoryImpl;
       //
  }
```

Main configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories()
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {
  // some db-settings
}
```

May be It doesn't matter is that case, but test-configurations is:

```
 @TestConfiguration
 public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public EntryRepositoryImpl mockEntryRepositoryImpl() {
         return Mockito.mock(EntryRepositoryImpl.class);
      }
 }
```

And, after running test, I receive the following exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entryRepositoryImpl':
```

caused by:

```
  NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.spb.budget_server.repository.EntryRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you used `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories`?

Comment: I use it in main configuration: @Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories()
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration.   I updated my question

Comment: Try this `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = {EntryRepository.class})`

Comment: Ah or maybe if you are using that in tests, try to use [@DataMongoTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/mongo/DataMongoTest.html) on top of your class and then you don't need event `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: I add @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = {EntryRepository.class}) in class MongoConfig, but receive the same exception...

Comment: I don't use embedded mongoldb, i'm only trying to mock repository